# Regain javafx focus

Tags: javafx, focus

I have an application which runs in background. With jkeymaster I have registered a global hotkey to be fired although my application is not the active one. This is working. I now want to switch my background app in foreground again. Tried with this code:

```
import com.tulskiy.keymaster.common.HotKey;
import com.tulskiy.keymaster.common.HotKeyListener;
import com.tulskiy.keymaster.common.Provider;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TestClientNotWorking extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws AWTException {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Btn said 'Hello World!'");
            }
        });

        HBox root = new HBox(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.requestFocus();

        Provider provider = Provider.getCurrentProvider(false);
        provider.register(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 
            InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK), 
            new HotKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHotKey(HotKey hotKey) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Recievd");
                        primaryStage.toFront();
                        btn.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What happens: 
My stage is brought back to foreground, but the focus still remains in the app, were it was before and is not transferred to my primaryStage. Can you please help my how I could gain this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do all the conditions mentioned in the doc apply to your Button `btn`? (Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus--)

Comment: No - the stage itself is not active and thus not focusable, because it is sent to background. I'd like to work some other things around and want to activate this javafx application with a single hotkey. Does this work somehow? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your stage to be in the foreground or not?

Comment: Yes, I am doing some stuff somewhere else on my machine and with an hotkey want to activate my javafx app, want to get this into foreground (which already works) and want to set the focus in it (which does not work yet) to e.g. input any text or press buttons, keys to do additional features....

Comment: @Markus Oley pls show btn initialization code

Comment: @Oleksandr Sorry - don't understand, can you please elabroate your answer a bit?

Comment: @MarkusOley he want's you to show the code you use to initialize your `btn` ;) It's always helpful for others to show code you use so we can understand what's happening. You might think this might not be important to the problem but it just might be!

Comment: @Markus Oley It is not easy to answer your question without reading full code. There are a lot of reasons why requestFocus() doesnt work properly. For example, make sure that btn reference is initialized only once (maybe you call requestFocus on the different object).

Comment: OK, I have pasted my complete code example, you have to add 'com.github.tulskiy:jkeymaster:1.2' as dependency as well

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and run the code. As far as I understand your expectations are:

- start application, register key hook
- minimize jfx window
- press key combination (alt shift space in your case)
- **result**: jfx window is in foreground state, 'Hello World' button is focused

btn.requestFocus() works properly on my OS without any changes but my guess you need to try setIconified\setMaximized instead of primaryStage.toFront();
I changed a little bit your code pls try it and let us know if it works as you want.

```
public class TestClientNotWorking extends Application {

    private final Provider provider = Provider.getCurrentProvider(false);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws AWTException {
        final Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Btn said 'Hello World!'");
            }
        });

        final HBox root = new HBox(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
        root.requestFocus();// remove focus from btn

        final KeyStroke stroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl SPACE");// stroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK | InputEvent.ALT_MASK);
        provider.register(stroke, new HotKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHotKey(final HotKey hotKey) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Recievd");
                        primaryStage.setIconified(false); // primaryStage.toFront();
                        btn.requestFocus(); // set focus on btn
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        provider.stop();
    }
}
```